# Terminal in Gnome for Arch Linux Not Working

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, archlinux

I've just installed Arch Linux and installed the gnome package (Note: Not gnome-extra)

I open Gnome using the `xinit gnome-session` command, as I have already installed X Window.

When I run that command, Gnome opens up and I'm presented with a white terminal titled "login". However, nothing I do in this terminal actually does anything. No commands work, nothing.

Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? There have been a few questions around similar to this, however none that have been properly answered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I hadn't set Gnome to startup automatically, so when you login to Arch Linux using your standard root login. Check that gnome is installed and works (Use: `xinit gnome-session`).

Create an account by going to Settings, Users, Create the account as Administrator. Logout of Gnome Log back in as root to your Arch Linux CLI Use the command: `systemctl enable gdm` The next time you reboot, you should be presented with the Gnome Login screen.

Answer (score 2):

After installing gnome session you need to append

```
exec gnome-sssion
```

at the end of your **.xinitrc** file located at your home.

when you get the **login:** prompt enter your username and then your password.
Once you're logged in type **startx** to start gnome session